# F1-F12 keys don't work

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap

I bought compact keyboard. F1 = Fn + 1 and F2 = Fn + 2 ...
[image]
But F1-F12 keys don't work on my Ubuntu 16.04. For example F1 makes brightness up. I checked keycodes of F1-F12 keys and they are invalid. So F1 returns 232 keycode (instead 67).

I tried fix it using: `xmodmap -e "keycode 232 = F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 XF86Switch_VT_1"` But it didn't help. F1 still change brightness. I tried remap other F1-F12 keys and no results. Xmodmap works only for non functional keys.

Is it possible to fix F1-F12 keys? (Swap keycodes?)

**Xmodmap configured correct but F1 still change brightness**:

```
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 232 = F1 F1 F1 XF86Switch_VT_1" # IT DON'T HELP!!

$ xmodmap -pke # everything is OK!
keycode  67 = F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 XF86Switch_VT_1 F1 F1 XF86Switch_VT_1
keycode 232 = F1 F1 F1 XF86Switch_VT_1

$xev # take a look: XKeysymToKeycode = 67... F1... everything is OK again...
KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x5000001,
    root 0xf5, subw 0x0, time 921326, (236,-87), root:(236,403),
    state 0x0, keycode 232 (keysym 0xffbe, F1), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 67
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
$sudo evtest 
Event: time 1497517949.369064, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1497517949.458895, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 224 (KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN), value 0

$ setxkbmap -print
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete+ledscroll(group_lock)"    };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)+capslock(swapescape)"    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

P.S. Also F1-F12 work properly on Windows.

### Update:

#### **Thank you @dirkt. Please take a look at the details:**

1. I use Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS **Unity**
2. `/dev/input/event11:    RK61 Bluetooth keyboard`
3. `sudo lsof /dev/input/event11` output: **acpid**, Xorg
4. `evtest --grab /dev/input/eventX` result: you are right, because the brightness of the Laptop screen **stay the same** (I've pressed Fn + 1 => F1)!

#### Trying to kill **acpid** process:

5. `sudo kill 757` // killing **acpid** process
6. `sudo lsof /dev/input/event11` output: Xorg // OK acpid killed
7. Pressing F1 -> Brightness is changing! // FAIL

#### Here is my rdesc file: https://pastebin.com/vxDvwMwr

#### Here is the hexdump: https:// pastebin.com/eT9mNnGV

Also I tried to change keycode via `xkbcomp` and it doesn't help.

Please write any thoughts. Thank you!

Comment: You could try to fix it manually, but the better way to do it is to set the proper `XkbLayout` / `XkbVariant` / `XkbModel` / whatever in `xorg.conf`.  You should be able to find the proper values if you do a search for `X11` and your keyboard's model.

Comment: Are you running Wayland, or X?

Comment: @dirkt I'm using X.

Comment: Hm. `xmodmap` only works for keycodes less 256, but that shouldn't be a problem for 232. And 232 is indeed mapped to  `XF86MonBrightnessDown`, so remapping *should* make it work. Can you verify with `xmodmap -pke` that the new mapping is installed, and with `evtest` (as root) that you really get keycode 232 for F1? What are the keycodes for the other F-keys? 233-243? What's the output of `setxkbmap -print`?

Comment: What model is it? There's often an option to choose whether Fn is the default.

Comment: @dirkt please take a look at just added code section to the topic.

Comment: @Gilles is Royal Kludge RK61 keyboard.

Comment: @dirkt thank you for response and please take a look at updated info in main post.

Answer (score 6):

I found solution here: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1063898-start-0.html

```
change behaviour on the fly 
# echo 2 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode 

or modify it in config 
[/etc/conf.d/modules] 
module_hid_apple_args="fnmode=2 iso_layout=0"
```

Comment: For Linux using systemd like ubuntu 16.04, /etc/conf.d/modules will no longer tale effect. Please refere https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407504/270128

Comment: It works for me on the fly on Ubuntu 20.04
But after reboot the configuration goes to previous mode. Refer this to fix the issue https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/609797/251660

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: The `xmodmap` mapping actually works correctly. As `xev` shows, you get `keysym 0xffbe` which is `F1`, as it should be.

So the question is (1) why it still changes brightness and (2) why it returns the keycode 232 (for `KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN`) instead of the one for the F1 key (67).

For (1), I suspect Ubuntu runs something by default the reads directly from `/dev/input` instead of processing X events, and this is processing the key no matter what `xmodmap` says. You didn't say which desktop environment you run (Gnome?). You can look with `lsof` for a process that directly reads the `/dev/input/eventX` source (you got the number X from `evtest`, numbers can change across boots). You can also test this theory by running `evtest --grab /dev/input/eventX`: This will make `evtest` the exclusive program to process the events, so when you press Fn+F1, it should still show `KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN`, but the brightness of your PC/Laptop screen should stay the same.

As for (2), googling the brand name shows it's a Bluetooth keyboard. This means it's likely a HID device. You can debug the by looking at `dmesg` to identify the corresponding `hidraw` device file and the bluetooth identifier. Then do

```
mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug
```

as root, and have a look at `sys/kernel/debug/hid/*/rdesc` for the correct device (look at available subdirectories). If you can't make sense of it, put it in a pastebin and edit the question with the link. Also, dump raw HID events using `hexdump -C /dev/hidrawX`, pressing Fn and F1, F2 etc several times. That should give you an idea why the kernel translates this the way it does.

**Edit**

Looking at the hidraw dump, the keyboard correctly produces scancodes `3a`, `3b` etc. for the function keys, as described in the HID descriptor.

So the problem must be in the HID-to-input translation layer.

You can interrogate this layer via ioctls. There's no public tool for this I know of, but I may put one up on github when it's done.

The only way to set this mapping I know is via the udev `hwdb` database as described e.g. [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes).

So I would guess who have some package installed that provides a database entry to map F1 to brightness control, and that also provides a program to react to this by directly monitoring `/dev/input/event*`. Try to see if you can find it on your system. `lsof` may help.

Comment: please take a look at the new details in the main post.